# Why is froala removing form tags from my html?

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, froala

I have a froala editor integrated into one of my web applications which is based on net core 3.1.
I use the code view to write html pages in it and switch back to the html view before I save the page to the DB. Every time I insert a form tag on the page and switch back to the html view and then back to the code view I notice that Froala has removed the form tags entirely!

Can anyone please highlight the issue here?

Settings I have tried:

`htmlUntouched: true,
 htmlRemoveTags: [],`

And as per the [Froala doc](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/#htmlAllowedTags):
[image: allowed tags]

The form tag is definitely allowed. So I fail to understand what is going wrong here.
Please let me know if you know the solution or any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `Every time I insert a form tag on the page and switch back to the html view and then back to the code view I notice that Froala has removed the form tags entirely` Which version of Froala Editor you are using? Besides, you can try to set **htmlAllowedTags** option with all default tags manually in your js code while initializing the Froala Editor, which might help fix this issue.

Comment: Froala version 3.1.
Regarding htmlAllowedTags isn't it allowed by default as I have highlighted in my question. I have shared an image from the docs.

Comment: Yes, `<form>` tag should be allowed by default, but it does not work in your app, so as I suggested, you can explicitly set htmlAllowedTags option in your js code and check if it could fix the issue.

Comment: I got rid of the forms and used JS to send all the details via ajax. There is also an iframe option to use form tags but just for one particular use case I did not see it fit to use iFrame options in froala. As it is my froala is globally initialized on app start.

Comment: @FeiHan Thanks for taking the time out though, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with browsers stripping out the `<form>` tag when the Froala editor is itself on the page inside a parent `<form>` tag. [One suggestion in the github bug reports](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/3490) is to change the settings to  `iframe: true`, although that may lead to other undesired consequences.